# Serivce Unavailable Error on Deployment from Pipeline Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-appservice

My Asp.net core MVC application deploys properly using a **pipeline to an Azure app service** that has deployment slots, but when I try to access the app in my browser, I receive a `"service unavailable error" message"`

When I **Stop and Start the app service the error goes away**, but the weird part is that deployment from Visual Studio works perfectly without the need to restart the app service.

I have tried app service stop and start from pipeline but it is also not working, a maunal restart required on deployment from pipeline.

My `CICD yaml pipeline` is multistage that deploys app on deployment slots.

I am stuck in there, can someone please help me out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution after days of digging and useless meetings with Microsoft support team.

**Solution**: What I found is that I set deploymentMethod as 'auto' in my pipeline task, which makes my application read-only after deployment on Azure AppService and limits the app size to 29.9 MBs while the actual size was 156 MBs.
So, I changed the deploymentMethod to 'zipDeploy' which deploy every file and folder of my application on webapp Azure with actual app size of 156 MBs that fixed the problem.

[image: Pipeline Deployement Task]

I am sharing this solution so it might save someone's several hours.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed `Asp.net` web app in Azure app service successfully by using the yaml script below:-

***I am using Standard App service plan for the deployment of Web app.***

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'subscription-id'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'valleywebapp09'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Check the logs: To see if there are any problems or warnings that might be the root of the problem, check the logs for your app service. By selecting "Log stream" from the "Monitoring" section of your app service in the Azure portal, you can retrieve the logs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Examine the pipeline configuration: You can examine the YAML pipeline configuration to determine whether there are any pipeline problems that might be preventing the app from launching correctly on the deployment slots.

Verify the initialization code for the app: If the programme is not starting up properly, you can check the startup code to see if there are any problems.

Check if the settings are synced correctly while swapping slots like below:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SiddheshDesai for this detailed answer, I will try it but my deployment process used slots that creates the problem. Deployment on web app without slots is working for me, I am facing issue on app service with slots.

Comment: I have tested your solution but still the same error, can you please guide me more where should I find the pipeline configurations and how to verify.